# OpenCV (Python) video subplots

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to show two OpenCV video feeds in the same figure as subplots, but couldn't find how to do it. When I try using `plt.imshow(...), plt.show()`, the window won't even appear. When I try using `cv2.imshow(...)`, it shows two independent figures. What I actually want are subplots :(. Any help?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    channels = cv2.split(frame)
    frame_merge = cv2.merge(channels)

    #~ subplot(211), plt.imshow(frame)
    #~ subplot(212), plt.imshow(frame_merged)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame merged', frame_merge)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**UPDATE:** Ideally the output should look something like that:

[image: Subplots for OpenCV videos]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may simply use the `cv2.hconcat()` method to horizontally join 2 images and then display using imshow, But keep in mind that the images must be of same **size** and **type** for applying `hconcat` on them.

You may also use `vconcat` to join the images vertically.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

bg = [[[0] * len(frame[0]) for _ in xrange(len(frame))] for _ in xrange(3)]

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Resizing down the image to fit in the screen.
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # creating another frame.
    channels = cv2.split(frame)
    frame_merge = cv2.merge(channels)

    # horizintally concatenating the two frames.
    final_frame = cv2.hconcat((frame, frame_merge))

    # Show the concatenated frame using imshow.
    cv2.imshow('frame',final_frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have just tried it, and it works beautifully. The problem is that I cannot place `matplotlib` style titles :( Any suggestions on that front?

Comment: If you can show the expected output, then I may be able to help you

Comment: @RafazZ did you find out how to add image titles in opencv?

Comment: Nope -- didn't find a way :(

Comment: You may try `vconcat` on each of the two images to add heading to each of them before doing the `hconcat` @Roxanne @RafazZ