# OpenCV subplots images with titles and space around borders

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am looking to display some images in **OpenCV Python** with titles and borders around the each subplot. something like this (courtesy of the following stackoverflow post: [OpenCV (Python) video subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669622/opencv-python-video-subplots)):

**WHAT I WANT:**
[image]

But I only manage to get this with that code adapted.

```
 import cv2
 im1 = cv2.imread('Lenna.png')
 final_frame = cv2.hconcat((im1, im1))
 cv2.imshow('lena', final_frame)
```

<s>**WHAT I HAVE**
[image]</s>

Is it possible to obtain this using OpenCV?
 I know a workaround would be to put text on the images, but that's not what I want because it will cover important information that way.

**UPDATE**

My bad, I didn't specify initially: **I have 4 subplots** (so 4 different images) and not two like in the example. Also, I want the solution to be as fast as possible since I have video (time restrictions)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a pretty quick and dirty solution. You can refine it to suit your needs. I have the explanation alongside the code as well:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

#--- Here I am creating the border---
black = [0,0,0]     #---Color of the border---
constant=cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=black )
cv2.imshow('constant',constant)
```

[image]

You can find many other options for different borders [ON THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html)

```
#--- Here I created a violet background to include the text ---
violet= np.zeros((100, constant.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
violet[:] = (255, 0, 180)
```

[image]

```
#--- I then concatenated it vertically to the image with the border ---

vcat = cv2.vconcat((violet, constant))
cv2.imshow('vcat', vcat)
```

[image]

```
#--- Now I included some text ---
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(vcat,'FRAME',(30,50), font, 2,(0,0,0), 3, 0)
cv2.imshow('Text', vcat)
```

[image]

```
#--- I finally concatenated both the above images horizontally---
final_img = cv2.hconcat((vcat, vcat))
cv2.imshow('Final', final_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Hope This answer helps. You can modify it to suit your requirement.

Comment: one minor comment. why don't you increase the size of the border on top in, e.g. `constant=cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,100,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=black )` . that way the violet rectangle is not necessary anymore. I am not looking for anything fancy, but for something fast& simple :)

Comment: As I said you can always modify it. You can also adjust the position of the text. :D

Comment: I hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 8):

The general idea would be to create a new image with `width += width/10` and `height += height/20`. Write some text as heading and place the input image along the center as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("/Users/anmoluppal/Downloads/Lenna.png")

height, width, ch = img.shape
new_width, new_height = width + width/20, height + height/8

# Crate a new canvas with new width and height.
canvas = np.ones((new_height, new_width, ch), dtype=np.uint8) * 125

# New replace the center of canvas with original image
padding_top, padding_left = 60, 10
if padding_top + height < new_height and padding_left + width < new_width:
    canvas[padding_top:padding_top + height, padding_left:padding_left + width] = img
else:
    print "The Given padding exceeds the limits."

text1 = "Sample Image 1"
text2 = "Sample Image 2"
img1 = cv2.putText(canvas.copy(), text1, (int(0.25*width), 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, np.array([255, 0, 0]))
img2 = cv2.putText(canvas.copy(), text2, (int(0.25*width), 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, np.array([255, 0, 0]))

final = cv2.hconcat((img1, img2))
cv2.imwrite("./debug.png", final)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey this is a more optimal solution. Great work mate !!!! Mine was rather quick and dirty :D

Comment: No Worries, Dude, Your solution is using inbuilt methods like `cv2.copyMakeBorder` instead of maths, which seems good to me , Thanks for appreciating :)

Answer (score 5):

I used the other answers to make a generalizable function which works for arbitrary row/columns:

```
def cvSubplot(imgs,     # 2d np array of imgs (each img an np arrays of depth 1 or 3).
              pad=10,   # number of pixels to use for padding between images. must be even
              titles=None,  # (optional) np array of subplot titles
              win_name='CV Subplot' # name of cv2 window
              ):
    '''
    Makes cv2 based subplots. Useful to plot image in actual pixel size
    '''

    rows, cols = imgs.shape

    subplot_shapes = np.array([list(map(np.shape, x)) for x in imgs])
    sp_height, sp_width, depth = np.max(np.max(subplot_shapes, axis=0), axis=0)

    title_pad = 30
    if titles is not None:
        pad_top = pad + title_pad
    else:
        pad_top = pad

    frame = np.zeros((rows*(sp_height+pad_top), cols*(sp_width+pad), depth ))

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            img = imgs[r, c]
            h, w, _ = img.shape
            y0 = r * (sp_height+pad_top) + pad_top//2
            x0 = c * (sp_width+pad) + pad//2
            frame[y0:y0+h, x0:x0+w, :] = img

            if titles is not None:
                frame = cv2.putText(frame, titles[r, c], (x0, y0-title_pad//4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .5, (255,255,255))

    cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Below is an example usage:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.random((40,400,1))
a2 = np.random.random((200,200,1))
a3 = np.random.random((100,100,1))
a4 = np.random.random((300,150,1))
a5 = np.random.random((100,150,1))
filler = np.zeros((0,0,1))

titles = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'Filler']])

imgs = np.array([[a1, a2, a3], [a4, a5, filler]])

cvSubplot(imgs, pad=20, titles=titles)
```

That script produces the following cv2 image:

[image]

Comment: If you have images of the same size, you have to be wary of the `numpy array` flattens the array of arrays to a n-dimensional array. In this case a five dimensional array. I haven't found a good way to force `numpy` to keep the array of arrays, but this workaround is working:

`a1 = np.random.random((300,300,1))`
`a2 = a1`
`imgs = np.empty([1,2], dtype=object)`
`imgs[0,0] = a1`
`imgs[0,1] = a2`